# broadcast is also broadcasting the same user who is typing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

every time I logged in and start typing the broadcast also broadcasts the same user who is typing until I refresh the page if I refresh it then it'll be good it broadcasts only to the other users.

**serverSide**

```
socket.on("typing", function (data) {
   socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit("typing", data.typing);
});
```

**clientSide**

```
useEffect((){
   socket.on("typing", function(data){
       setTyping(data);
    })
}, [socket, setTyping])
```

how to fix this without refreshing the page.

Comment: Did my answer help you @khalid-hussein? If so, please set my answer as the prefered answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

To be able to send to all users except sender in a specific room, you need to use `socket.to(data.room).emit('typing', data.typing);`

[As by socketio cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/)